# Can virtualbox be used to profit from a more recent kernel ? [ Or: does a recent kernel on the guest, could handle hardware the host can't ? ]

Tags: kernel, virtualbox

At my office I have a linux machine (ubuntu 16.04) and a tablet wacom (one) that I can't use with  this machine.
On more recent distros  this tablet work out of the box.

I can't upgrade  my system, but I can install a recent distros  on a virtualbox on my system, that is a distribution  that handles this tablet out of the box.

My question is, would this allow  the virtual machine to  use the tablet ? or does the fact that the host kernel can't handle the tablet will impeach the guest to do so ?

Cheers,

PS: I can't just install the wacom driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using VirtualBox, you can to pass through USB devices to guests. You can give your guest access to your tablet, and the guest kernel will have full access to it regardless of the host kernel’s level of support.